# queue ImportError in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure why I am getting this `ImportError`. `queue.Queue()` is in the documentation.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#queue.Queue

I am using it in a function like so:

`node_queue = queue.Queue()`

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_jabba.py", line 15, in <module>
    from utils import gopher, jsonstream, datagen, event_gen, tree_diff, postal
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/QE/TrinityTestFramework/poc/utils/tree_diff.py", line 5, in <module>
    import queue
ImportError: No module named queue
```

Line 5 is `import queue`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys                      # access to basic things like sys.argv
import os                       # access pathname utilities
import argparse                 # for command-line options parsing
import queue
```

Comment: Do you have a vanilla python implementation?  Where/how did you download/install it?

Comment: Also, can you run `python --version`?  Its possible you're actually running Python 2.x, in which case the `queue` module was named `Queue`

Comment: @Dannnno the command gave me 2.7.6. I thought if I had the `#!/usr/bin/env python3`  on top it wouldn't matter?

Comment: I'm not an expert on shebang lines so I'm not positive exactly how those work.  From a cursory google search what you have should work though.  I'm assuming you're running this on a Linux machine?

Comment: How are you invoking your script? If you say `python tree_diff.py`, the shebang won't matter. It's only inspected if you execute the file directly, like `./tree_diff.py`.

Comment: @Dannnno running on OSX

Comment: @AndrewLorente I imported the module to use the function in another file

Comment: That should be fine then, I should have said a Unix based machine

Comment: @AndrewLorente I am running another program like so `./program.py` and this program invokes functions from `tree_diff.py`

Comment: Ah yeah, then the shebang in `tree_diff.py` won't matter at all. It's down to what python is specified by `program.py`.

Comment: I believe the issue you're encountering has to do with how you run your other script (`./test_jabba.py`), not with anything in the `tree_diff` module. Even if you fixed the issue with `queue`, you'd probably have issues elsewhere, since there are a good number of differences between Python 2 and 3. For whatever reason, your script is being run in Python 2, not Python 3 as you intend (and as the `tree_diff` module requires). Unfortunately, you haven't provided much information about how you're running `test_jabba.py`. Does it have a `#!` line at the top? How are you invoking it?

Comment: @Blckknght evey file has `#!/usr/bin/env python3` on top. Might be an installation issue because I do not see `python3` in `/usr/bin/` but it is located in another directory

Comment: How are you running the file? Are you calling it as a script with `./test_jaba.py` from the shell, double clicking on it in a window, or running the interpreter explicitly? The third (and maybe the second) will not make use of the `#!` line. If you're calling `python test_jaba.py`, try using `python3 test_jaba.py` instead. If you're using one of the other approaches to run it, I don't know what the issue is (I'm not very knowledgeable about MacOS), but please describe it more thoroughly, so that perhaps somebody else will know what to do.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A kinda standard cross py2-py3 compatible version:

```
try: 
    import queue
except ImportError:
    import Queue as queue
```

Comment: This stops the immediate ImportError, but it doesn't do anything about the deeper problem of actually being on Python 2 when you were trying to use Python 3.

Answer (score 30):

Another way to avoid version problems is:

```
import sys
is_py2 = sys.version[0] == '2'
if is_py2:
    import Queue as queue
else:
    import queue as queue
```

Comment: There is a simplified solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021998/99834 -- less code, does the same, no side effects.

Comment: @sorin: what do you mean by "no side effects"? you are importing module, catching exception, those are statements with side effects

Comment: importing sys, which was not needed. anyway what one would use is matter of personal preference, both approaches do work.

Answer (score 5):

for *ImportError: No module named 'Queue'* in Python3, just replace the sentence "*import Queue*" with "*import queue as Queue*".

Answer (score 1):

Replace `#!/usr/bin/env python3` with `#!/usr/bin/python3`

If your env isn't set up correctly then `#!/usr/bin/env python3` may not work. If `#!/usr/bin/python3` gives the same error then try running `/usr/bin/python3 --version` in your shell as a sanity check.

If you don't get a sensible output from `/usr/bin/python3 --version` then you have odd installation of python 3 and I suggest installing it using your package manager (`apt-get`, `yum`, `homebrew` or whatever you prefer - this will probably fix the `!#/usr/bin/env` issue).

Comment: What happens when you type `/usr/bin/python3 --version` ?

Comment: I get a no such directory or file

Comment: OK - what happens when you type `/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: same output. However I did this:

`mtvl1289dd026:bin bli1$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2
mtvl1289dd026:bin bli1$ pwd
/usr/bin
`

Comment: So /usr/bin/env python3 gives you `no such directory or file` ? That sounds like your problem. What happens when you type `which python3`

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3`

Comment: I guess the paths are causing an issue. How would I fix this so that my `shebang` would work in this case?

Comment: OK -r it sounds like your python install is a bit unusual. Put `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3` at the top of your file and I expect it will work - this is *not* a permanent solution of course

Comment: I'm guessing you installed python 3 in a way which was somehow unorthodox? Try installing using your package manager (see my addition to my answer)

Comment: Okay so it turns out python3 is not located in `/usr/bin/` I tried `brew install python3` but I am getting `Error: python3-3.4.1_1 already installed`

Comment: `ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3` might work. But really this appears to be an issue with your installation, there will be a way to uninstall and reinstall with brew.

Comment: Just tried the command and it did not work. I agree it is probably an installation issue and it is not installed in the correct directory

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3, try

```
from queue import Queue
queue = Queue()
```

ref:https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 3.6

```
import queue as Queue

workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
```

This method works for me.